# Create Virtual Hosts in Vagrant Server

Tags: php, apache, vagrant, localhost, vagrantfile

I am running Apache server with vagrant and I want to access multiple websites from host machine. Current setup looks like this:

**Vagrantfile:**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    config.ssh.forward_agent = true
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80, host_ip: "127.0.0.1", id: 'apache_http'
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 443, host_ip: "127.0.0.1", id: 'apache_https'
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 22, host_ip: "127.0.0.1", id: 'ssh'
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/"
end
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.33.10 website.com
192.168.33.10 a.website.com
192.168.33.10 b.website.com
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/website.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
    ServerName website.com
    ServerAlias www.website.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/website/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/website/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName website.com
    ServerAlias www.website.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/website/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/website/error.log
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/website.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/website.cert
</VirtualHost>
```

I can access the website from inside vagrant box by: `curl https://website.com -k`. How can I expose it to the host machine?

Comment: you should just be able to use the same way `https://website.com` will point to your VM with the change you made to your host file. note when you enable a static IP you dont need to forward port from guest as you'll access your VM/guest using the IP directly

Comment: you need to update `/etc/hosts` on host machine as well.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri: Removed forwarded port lines from vagrant file.

Comment: @AlexBlex: How can I change `/etc/hosts` on host machine? I am using windows.

Comment: on windows the file is in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

Comment: @FrédéricHenri: Thanks! It's working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steps are correct.

1. In your Vagrantfile you dont need to add the forwarding port if you use a static IP as you'll access your VM/guest using the IP directly
2. You need to update the hosts file from your host machine. On windows the file is located under `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

You can now access `https://website.com` directly from your host